# Returning the altered (by apoc.trigger) version of node instead of the original

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-driver

I am using the python bolt driver to create nodes in a neo4j database. These nodes get altered by `apoc.trigger` functions. And i want the returning `BoltStatementResult` to contain the altered version of these nodes.

This is what i have tested so far:

1. My triggers are working as expected. The nodes stored, are altered correctly.
2. I tried the 'before' and 'after' phases.
3. I set the trigger functions to return the altered version.
4. I did write a second query to get the new and updated node of database. But this option is quite unsafe, as it has no unique identifier.

My trigger function:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
    'onCreateNodeAddMetadata',
    'UNWIND {createdNodes} AS n
     SET n.uid = apoc.create.uuid(), n.timestamp = timestamp() RETURN n',
    {phase: 'before'}
)
```

I expect the returning value of my `session.write_transaction` to contain the the added properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a safe workaround (but see caveat below), the Cypher query in your `write_transaction` can return the native ID of the created node (e.g., `RETURN ID(n)`).

Then, ***as long as you know the node was not deleted***, you can perform a query for it with that ID (in this example, `myID` contains the ID value and is passed as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)):

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = $myId
...
```

*If the node could be deleted before you search for it by native ID, then this technique is not safe, since neo4j can re-assign the native ID of a deleted node to another newly- created node.*

Comment: I tried to get around the internal id. But since i am not planning to implement delete triggers. I think this is the way to go, for now. Thanks.